# Admob deprecating versions 6.4.1

Tags: admob, deprecated

i have received email that Admob will  deprecating versions 6.4.1.

1. is this include ads in iOS too?// i'm not yet migrate my ios project to switf 2 yet :(
2. for "ensure that your ads continue to serve" is this mean it will stop serve or just may or may not serve?

Thanks